# A PHP function to check for cookies

Tags: php

I've written a php function and some helper functions that checks for cookies when somebody lands on a page but it's not so fast. I want to know is there any way to make it faster or improve it i know it's possible to check for cookies client side using javascript but what if it is disabled also so i need a pure server side solution.

```
<?php

function check_cookie(){
    if(is_cookie_disabled()){
        header("location:cookie_is_disabled.php");
        exit;
    }        
}

function is_cookie_disabled(){
    $curr_url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if(isset($_COOKIE['testCookie']) && !(isset($_COOKIE['cookie']))){
        $original_url = original_url ($curr_url);
        header("location: ".$original_url);
        setcookie("cookie", 'enabled');
        exit;
    } elseif(!(isset($_COOKIE['testCookie']))) {
        if(isset($_GET['temp'])){                
            return true;
        } else{
            if(if_parameters_exist_in_url($curr_url)){
                $url = $curr_url."&temp=temp";
            } else {
                $url = $curr_url."?temp=temp";
            }
            header("location: ".$url);
            setcookie("testCookie", 'test');
            exit;              
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function original_url ($curr_url){
    if (!empty($_GET)){
        if (isset($_GET['temp'])) {
            if(count($_GET)>0){
                return removeqsvar($curr_url, 'temp');
            } else {
                return removeallvars($curr_url);
            }
        }
    }
    return $curr_url;
}    

function removeqsvar($url, $varname) {
    return preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$url);
}

function removeallvars($url){
    return $url = strtok($url, '?');
}

function if_parameters_exist_in_url($url){
    if (strpos($url, '=')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}    

//at the top of your pages
check_cookie();

?>
```

Comment: How slow is it? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Look, people with cookies and JavaScript both disabled are few and far between. You're spending more time than it's worth dealing with.

Comment: @sarnold as fast as possible

Comment: yeah but both cookies and javascript are crucial to website performance and i wanna have complete control on them

Answer (score 2):

It could be slow from all of the location redirects. But I've never done anything like that so I can't be sure.

Is it possible to lazily set the cookies. For instance, set a session and cookie on the first page load. And then, on the second page load check if the cookie is present.

This is how you could check if the page has loaded.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['first_load'] = isset($_SESSION['first_load']) ? false : true;

if( !$_SESSION['first_load'] && isset($_COOKIE['testCookie']) )
  echo 'cookies enabled!'
else
  echo 'no cookies for you!'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not slow. Measure the time it takes:

- to execute this code (using `microtime(true)`),
- and for your browser to receive the page (eg. Chrome has a "Network" tab in the Developers Tool).

You'll see that optimizing this code won't yield any improvement, since this PHP code probably takes a few milliseconds to execute while the page load can take up to a second for small pages.